# what does the symbol "\" mean in python?

Tags: python

I don't get what this symbol("\") means at the end of the code.

is this symbol tells the preprocessor to ignore the next code?

```
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, L: int, R: int) -> int:
        if not root:
            return 0
        return self.rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R) + \ 
                self.rangeSumBST(root.right, L, R) + \
                (root.val if L <= root.val <= R else 0)
```

Comment: breaks the code line

Comment: The `"\"` in your snippet indicates that the next line should be joined to this line. (without the `"\"` itself)

Comment: [2.1.5. Explicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a line continuation. A multiline statement is more typically done by enclosing the statement in parentheses. But, you can also use the backslash character to tell the interpreter to treat the next line as a continuation of the current line.

Answer (score 1):

Python is the indentation language. So if you remove the "backslash", it can give you the error because of the invalid syntax. The "\" can tell python that next line continues the content of the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to break a long line of code into two lines without getting *Indentation Error*.

Comment: _..into two lines .._ Or even more :)

Comment: @B001ᛦ: I initially wrote "several", but then realized it wasn't so true. One `/` allows to split one line into two lines. No more and no less.