# What does a backslash at the end of a line mean?

Tags: python, syntax

In this exercise i was supposed to capitalise everything that needs to be capitalised like the "I"s or the first letter of a new sentence etc..

In my attempt i tried to use "=", but python doesn't allow that. So i just looked at the solutions. In the following solution the author uses " + \ " (with comment), can someone tell me what that is what that does? I tried to put them in one line but then the IDE would give me an error message.

```
def capitalize(s):
    result = s.replace(" i ", " I ")
    if len(s) > 0:
        result = result[0].upper() + \ # this part, what is this + \? if i put them in one line, 
                                       # the IDE would give me an error message
                 result[1 : len(result)]
    pos = 0

    while pos < len(s):
        if result[pos] == "." or result[pos] == "I" or result[pos] == "?":
            pos = pos + 1

            while pos < len(s) and result[pos] == " ":
                pos = pos + 1

            if pos < len(s):
                result = result[0 : pos] + \
                    result[pos].upper() + \
                    result[pos + 1 : len(result)]
        pos = pos + 1

    return result

def main():
    s = input("Enter some text: ")
    capitalized = capitalize(s)
    print("It is capitalized as:", capitalized)

main()
```

Comment: `+` is string concatenation. The `\` is used to split the long line across several lines. If you want everything on one line, then remove the `\`.

Comment: @ndc85430 you probably want to double your backslashes like `\\`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198885/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) is an even better duplicate.

Comment: Jerry, please take some time to read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Along with "I get an error", you should also tell us what that error is, in the interest of asking a complete question. Writing the title is another area that is often overlooked -- you should summarize your _actual_ question, which is essentially "what does a backslash at the end of a line do?". Searching for that question should already give you some results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New lines often signal the end of a statement to the python interpreter. 
There are however a few exceptions to this rule:

### Semicolon

```py
x=5; y=6; z=x+y; print(z);
```

In the code above, the semicolon (`;`) is used to signal the end of a statement, and thus allows multiple statements to be written on a single line.

### New line

```py
# This is a comment before a statement
x=5
y=6
z=x+y
print(z)  # This is a comment after a statement
```

The code above makes use of the new line to separate statements from each other, and is legitimate python code. Also note that you can place a comment before a statement, however, a new line separates the comment from the statement. Note: A semicolon cannot be used at the end of a comment to separate the comment from a statement.  eg. `# This is a comment ; x=5; y=6;` 
However, a comment can be placed on the same line as a statement provided it is placed at the end of the statement. eg. `print(z) # This is a comment after a statement`.

### Backslash

```py
x = 5
y = 6
z = x + \
    y       # comment after statement is ok
print(z)
```

A backslash `\` can be used to carry a statement over to another line(s) provided:

- There are no other characters (including spaces) on the same line, after the backslash.
- The subsequent lines are indented appropriately
- Comments occur at the end of the statement, not in between.

### Brackets

```py
x = 5
y = 6
z = (x +     # comments can happen in the middle of a statement
    y)       # comment after statement is ok
print(z)

a = [5,      # comments can happen here too
     6,
     7,
     8]
```

This is an example of how brackets `() + []` tend to break the rules a bit. Whereby you can place comments at the end of a line, but within a statement.

There are probably some other rules that I have not thought of, but the reason you are getting an error in your example above is because you are trying to place a comment in the middle of a statement. I hope this clarifies the issue somewhat.